# Url Link and Parameter Passing in Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used the IsPostedFromThisSIte model to protect from unnecessary parameter in the url for security purpose

```
 [Mywebsite.Models.SecurityModels.URLHash.IsPostedFromThisSite, HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(HttpException), View = "Error")]
```

But now the problem is that when i am changing the parameter from inspect elementof the browser than it is not working and parameter are passing

So what should i do to remove this bugs?can i hide the url in inspect element of the browser

Answer (score 2):

You might try modifying the logic for your `IsPostedFromThisSite` attribute to detect whether you're in debug mode via `IsDebuggingEnabled` on the context.

If debugging, you can then just skip the check.